# SORT BY date in left+right union join table

Tags: sql, sorting, join

I have 2 tables with lots of identical data (applies for manufacturing of businesscards in 2 languages).

I `JOIN` (emulate FULL OUTER join as far as i know, doing LEFT UNION RIGHT JOIN) them to show the data side by side for easy copying.

```
table a has data in language1
table b has data in language2
```

Not every person have both language1 and language2 data, so have just language1 or just language2.

I do a query like that:

```
SELECT
<long list of selected rows from table a and table b as afiled,bfield>
FROM tablelanguage1 a 
LEFT JOIN tablelanguage2 b
ON a.email=b.email
UNION
SELECT<long list of selected rows from table a and table b as afiled,bfield>
FROM tablelanguage1 a 
RIGHT JOIN tablelanguage2 b
ON b.email = a.email
ORDER BY adatetime DESC, bdatetime DESC
```

This shows everything just as i need but i have troubles with sorting: it shows everything but `language2-only entries correctly`. Language2-only(table b) entries are always last, even if the date is later than some of `language1+language2` or `language1-only` entries.

Any suggestions on how to code`ORDER BY` correctly in that situation? Thanks alot!

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?  Why emulate a `FULL JOIN` instead of using a `FULL JOIN`?

Comment: using  libmysql - 5.5.31. Emulating cause it gave me 'cannot parse query' on full join (and yeeeeeah, im pretty noob in sql stuff)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fix this with the `COALESCE()` function:

```
ORDER BY COALESCE(adatetime,bdatetime) DESC
```

`COALESCE()` returns the first non-NULL value from a set.  The result you were getting makes sense, because for all those 'language2-only' records the `adatetime` was `NULL`.  Multiple fields in `ORDER BY` are treated as a heirarchy, so all those `NULL` values get sorted together, then it considers the `bdatetime` value.  `COALESCE()` will order all records by whichever date is populated, instead of first one then the other.

Comment: I knew it was something really simple... Thanks alot, works like a charm!
And yeah, the result i was getting made sense for me, i just didnt know how to get the result i wanted!